# Can't implement flex-wrap, grid in external style sheet

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position

--

I have an assignment that provides code from HTML page and an external CSS stylesheet, and I'm not supposed to change the HTML code or create any new stylesheet selectors, only add property:value to what's already there.

All of the examples I'm seeing for using grid boxes, changing navigation bar from vertical to horizontal, etc. use a bunch of divs, but those are not already in use in the HTML code. How do I alter selectors to implement flex-wrap and grid options without using divs?

**Example of HTML:**

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Our history</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Example of CSS:

```
  nav {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: .5em;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
  }
```

Example of one assignment instruction:

--The navigation bar should scroll with the content and then become stuck at the top of the viewport when it reaches it.

I understand that I need to use "position: sticky" somewhere, but if I just put it under the "nav {" selector, it doesn't work. Same with similar attempts with flexbox, grid...

Answer (score 0):

When using `position: sticky`, you also need to define where it should stick. If you want to stick it at the very top and keep it there, remember to include `top: 0;`.

```css
  nav {
    background-color: #000;
    padding: .5em;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  nav a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
  }
```

```html
<main>
  <div>Block of text</div>
    <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Our history</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Contacts</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div style="height: 100vh;"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured that out, and was able to figure out other parts of the assignment that used flex-shrink, float, and a grid. I appreciate your help!! As frustrating as it can be when something isn't working, it is fun when you figure it out :)